# UIGestureRecognizer blocking buttons in table cell views

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I am using a custom UIGestureRecognizer on a UITableView.

As soon as I add the GestureRecognizer to the view, the buttons inside my table cells stop working (although changing the visible state to pressed, no action is being called).

And I am using `[self setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];` and no recognizer chaining or what-so-ever.

Any ideas anyone?

Best regards,

Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible that you are running into an issue with delaysTouchesEnded. Setting it to NO may fix your problem. Have a look at the docs.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html